# Show values of List<string[]> without using extra variables or using the foreach loop

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have fallen into a doubt and I don't know how to solve it, the case is:

I have created an "arrayed string" list like this:

```
List<string[]> definitions;
```

I have added to it values like this:

```
definitions.Add(new string[2] { "A", "Def.1" });
definitions.Add(new string[2] { "B", "Def.2" });
```

In order to show the values I do it like this:

```
foreach (string[] theDefinition in definitions)
{
Console.WriteLine(theDefinition[0] + "\tdef: " + theDefinition[1]);
}
```

So far this works fine, but how can I show the values without the foreach I mean something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(definitions[0] ...)
```

What should I write in the 3 dots to show either the "A" or the "Def.1" from the list in index 0.

I guess overcoming this is by doing something like:

```
string[] temp = definitions[0]
Console.WriteLine(temp[0] + ", " + temp[1]);
```

How to achieve it just using the Console.WriteLine without using extra variables, is this possible? and how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the support, I will just choose as answer the first one, I hope everybody will be fine with it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(definitions[0][0]  + "\tdef: " + definitions[0][1]);
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, I was trying using [,] in the string array this is why it wasn't working ;)

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to declare a definition type

```
public class Definition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + "\tdef: " + Value;   
    }
}
```

Now you can simplify your code like this

```
List<Definition> definitions = new List<Definition> {
    new Definition { Name = "A", Value = "Def.1" },
    new Definition { Name = "B", Value = "Def.2" },
};

foreach (Definition theDefinition in definitions)    
{    
    Console.WriteLine(theDefinition);    
}
```

Of cause you can use a fluent version of it as proposed by Nikhil Agrawal, which is now even simpler.

```
definitions.ForEach(def => Console.WriteLine(def));
```

prints

```
A   def: Def.1
B   def: Def.2
```

---

And accessing the fields is more descriptive than using array indexes

```
Definition def = definitions[0];
Console.WriteLine(def.Name + ", " + def.Value);

// compared to
// Console.WriteLine(temp[0] + ", " + temp[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct of course but why not just use a Dictionary instead of List of a 2 dimensional string array.

```
        var definitions = new Dictionary<string, string> 
        {
            { "A", "Def.1" },
            { "B", "Def.2" }
        };

        foreach (var keypair in definitions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \tdef: {1} ", keypair.Key, keypair.Value);
        }
```

Comment: I have heard about it but barely i.e. I have never used it, thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this: `definitions[definition_index][string_index]`.

Try:

```
Console.WriteLine(definitions[0][0] + "\tdef: " + definitions[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**One Line Answer instead of 3 Lines. No use of For or foreach Loop or Extra Variable when LINQ is here**

```
definitions.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x[0] + "\tdef: " + x[1]));
```

Comment: In what way(s) is this preferable to using a real foreach loop?

Comment: @Servy Definitely reduces my lines of code and clutter less than earlier code.

Comment: `foreach(var x in definitions){Console.WriteLine(x[0] + "\tdef: " + x[1]);}`  Not sure how that's so much more code.  It's the same number of lines and a whopping 5 characters longer.  The only thing making your code particularly short is that you're using single letter variable names rather than a meaningful name, which really shouldn't be done in either case.  `x` should be called `definition` or something similar.  If the line breaks bothers you in a regular foreach then simply remove them, done and done.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < definitions.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(definitions[i][0] + "\tdef: " + definitions[i][1]);
}
```